# Some parameters not posting to action method using postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I'm using MVC with .net 4.7 to create a REST api that I can use to post some data to.  Right now, as a test, I'm posting four string parameters to a method called "AddImage" which should receive these parameters.  When I test the post using postman I am only getting two parameters that come into the method and the other two don't come in at all.

Original example:
For example I will post

{
    "imagefile": "asdf",
    "filename": "aswd",
    "siteid": "asdf",
    "isCreateThumbnail": "false"
}

but when I debug the method in MVC the only parameters with any value are "filename" and "isCreateThumbnail".

```
//MVC method
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddImage(string imagefile, string filename, string siteid, string isCreateThumbnail = "true")
        {
            logEvent(6, "API_AddImage", string.Format("Params: filename:{0}, siteid:{1}, isCreateThumbnail:{2}", filename, siteid, isCreateThumbnail), "", 1);
           return View();
        }
```

[image]

I've tried adding all the parameters as part of an object and passing that, but maybe I'm doing that wrong too:

```
//Code from project
public struct imagedetails
    {
        public string imagefile;
        public string filename;
        public string siteid;
        public string isCreateThumbnail;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddImage(imagedetails image)
    {
        logEvent(6, "API_AddImage", string.Format("Params: filename:{0}, siteid:{1}, isCreateThumbnail:{2}", image.filename, image.siteid, image.isCreateThumbnail), "", 1);
        return View();
    }
```

I'm posting the object like this from postman:

{ "image":{
    "imagefile": "asdf",
    "filename": "aswd",
    "siteid": "asdf",
    "isCreateThumbnail": "false"
}
}

Comment: Please post screenshots of your request in postman

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've added a link to an image.  My rep doesn't allow me to fully add an image yet.

Comment: Added the image in the body for you

Comment: Just a guess here but shouldn't you be passing in the entries as strings rather than as part of an object? Conversely, you could wrap your parameters into an object on the c# side.

Comment: This might sound dumb, but how would I pass the parameters as just strings?

Comment: As an array of strings perhaps? ["", "", ""....] etc.

Comment: In your recent update, add `[FromBody]` to your signature `public ActionResult AddImage([FromBody]imagedetails image)`.

Comment: I think [FromBody] is only available to .net core and not .net 4.7.  I've tried creating a new project and setting it up the same way and it appears to work that way.  I'm still trying to figure out what might be causing my main solution to not work correctly.  I'm starting to think that this might be a visual studio bug?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all i highly suggest you putting those string parameters into a model, this way your code will be much cleaner and easier to write from this point on (for example passing arguments to class that does something with them). In fact this may even solve your problem all along.

As for separate parameters i can only guess that default value may be messing things up. Remove parameters and try adding them one by one, this way you'll know for sure what is wrong.

Comment: I'm updating the post.  Just tried putting the parameters into a model, but I'm not confident that I am testing it from postman correctly.

Comment: Data you're posting looks just fine. I thought casings might be off at first, but those are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for trying to help me figure out the issue with the code.  I ended up restarting my computer and looking in the web.config and finding a fix.  I changed two things, in the web.config I noticed that the tag "system.web" was setup with two different .net frameworks:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
```

The second thing that I changed was updating the running configuration to "Debug".  I'm not sure why it was set to "Release", but maybe I did that accidentally.